# Cocoa Touch - setting text of header of UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to set the title of the header of my entire UITableView, but am having no success.

I am trying to replicate creating the "Countries" header programmatically. I have a UITableView that works and displays data. When I insert the following line:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Countries";
```

In my viewDidLoad method, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.title = @"Countries";
```